# how to get next month from given month

Tags: php, strtotime

Here is my code for getting next month value i.e 12 but this output `01`

```
<?php
    $month = '11';
    $month =  Date("m", strtotime($month. " +1 month"));
    echo $month;
    ?>
```

i also tried this

```
<?php
$month = '11';
$month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
echo $month;
?>
```

and got this result

```
2678411
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use date() and strtotime() you can add a complete date to the month it works.

```
$month = '11';
$month =  Date("m", strtotime("2017-" . $month . "-01" . " +1 month"));
echo $month;
```

https://3v4l.org/IJBKU

This code will work for any input month and any year in the future, unless the calendar changes completely some day.
Whatever month you input it will output next month number

Comment: Working fine but Why are you using 2017 and 01? please explain

Comment: To get a true date. When you use only a month or a day you don't know what time or day in month PHP selects. Say it selects January 31 and you add one month to it. The output becomes March. Because February does not have 31 days. Therefore I select a true date.

Comment: This code does not output a number, it outputs a string with a leading zero to have it 2 bytes long. If somebody set `declare(strict_types=1);` then the `month` *string* will cause an error.

Comment: Number != Integer. Integer is a datatype that is a number. A number is a mathematical term or a typographical way of explaining a quantity. You can have a number in a word document. But you can't have a integer there, well you can but not in a strict manner. @Code4R7

Comment: A string isn't a number either, while an `int` is most certainly a number. I don't think it's a problem for the OP because the value of `$month` is a string too.

Comment: @Code4R7 a string can certainly be a number. Again you are thinking that number == int. But it's not. A number is just a number. Because this seems to confuse you, you can read about numbers here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number . Again number is **not** a datatype. It's a word.

Comment: Numbers are a [collection of datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html). `string` is not in that collection. While *["An integer is a number"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)*

Answer (score 2):

With `strtotime()`:

```
$nextmonth = date('n', strtotime('2000-' . $month . '-01 + 1 month'));  // returns string
```

Without `strtotime()`:

```
$nextmonth = $month % 12 + 1;  // returns integer
```

Comment: i want to add using strtotime function

Comment: @dan see my answer

Comment: Don't you think adding year "2000" is very similar to my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [date_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) like this 1 liner:

```
<?php
echo date_create()->modify('+1 month')->format('m');
?>
```

Comment: That does not take the `11` in account. But of course that might be sufficient for the OP.

Comment: Your right, im hoping the OP does not simply want 11 for eternity, else the OP may as well just use `<?= 12 ?>`.

Comment: i have to add 1 to input month of the user

Answer (score 2):

```
$month = 1;
echo $nextMonth = $month === 12 ? 1 : ++$month;
```

Or simply for just next month using date and strtotime

```
echo date('m', strtotime('+1 month'));
```